# How to disable the NSUndoManager for certain actions/entities with CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, nsundomanager

I work with `CoreData` on `OSX` (but I guess the problem is the same for `iOS`).

I would like to disable the undo management for the creation/deletion of `NSManagedObjects`. But, if possible, I would to keep the undo management for the attributes (like `NSStrings`, etc.) of my entities.

**How can I do that?**

If possible, I would like a global solution, such as subclass `MyManagedObject`of `NSManagedObject` with overwritten methods (`awakeFromInsert`, `prepareForDeletion`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decide a associate no `NSUndoManager` to a `NSManagedObjectContext` :

```
    [self.managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil] ;
```

Answer (score 5):

`NSUndoManager` has `disableUndoRegistration` and `enableUndoRegistration` methods to allow this. You need to intercept the operations that you don't want to be undoable and disable/enable the undo manager as appropriate. Note that calls to enable and disable must balance (don't call one without also calling (or having called) the other. It is also your responsibility to ensure that undoing any operation doesn't result in invalid state (this is the purpose of `beginUndoGrouping`).

Comment: I hope I could have found a way to do this globally : all creations/deletions would have be ignored by the `NSUndoManager`...

Comment: How often would that feature be used? And how often would it result in a context that can't be saved (validation issues)? This feature may be useful to you but it is unlikely to be useful to many people so I can't say I expect it would ever be added. You can wrap it in a subclass or helper methods...

Comment: Indeed, even just doing what you're thinking could cause issues for you in the future - tread carefully...

Comment: I don't understand why preventing undoing/redoing can create problems!

Comment: Do your entities have any non-optional attributes?

Comment: I don't think so. Now I see.